# Catched rejected promises via Promise.resolve arent recognized by Promise.all [UI5]

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sapui5

given an `promisesArray`, if you were to add `promises` in this manner:

```
promisesArray.push(
    Promise.resolve(promise1)
        .catch((err) => {
           console.log("Hello World");
        })
);
```

If some of the `promises` were to be catched with `Promise.resolve`, the later `Promise.all` isn't going to recognize this `promises` as rejected

```
Promise.all(promisesArray)
 .then(()=> {
   //do something
  }, catch => {
   //error handling
  })
```

Hence going to the `.then` do something block

**Question**: What to do in this situation if you want `Promise.all` to do the catch block ?

Comment: don't handle rejection in the first place ... or rethrow the error if you want the console.log - but, if one promise rejects in the Promise.all, ONLY the `catch` will be called with the first rejection reason

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Promise.allSettled'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead of `Promise.all` to get an array of `{status, value}` objects which allows you to check which promises succeeded and which failed after the event. The push phase simplifies to

```
promisesArray.push( promise1) // etc
```

Afterwards you can check what happened:

```
Promise.allSettled(promisesArray).then( resultArray => {
    resultArray.forEach( (result, index) =>
       if( result.status == "fulfilled") {
           console.log( "promise %s was rejected with reason", index, result.reason);
       }
       else {
           console.log( "promise %s was fulfilled with value", index, result.value); 
       }
   })
);
```